# Regular expression to match strings between the two same characters from a selection of different characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to match every characters that are between two `a` or two `b` but not between an `a` and a `b`.

For example:

```
accccca → should match
bfffffb → should match
azzzzzb → shouldn't match
bttttta → shouldn't match

ammbmma → should match from the a to the a
bllalla → should match only between the two a
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is to be matched if the string were `'ababcba'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern: `(a|b)(.*)\1`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NyWoDF/2)

**Explanation**

- `(...)` A captured group (group 1)
- `a|b` Match with a or b.
- `(.*)` Match with any character zero or more times and capture this as group 2
- `\1` Match with the captured group, if the group captured "a" the \1 means "a". basically, it means what you match in start using that in this place.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like `a.+a|b.+b` should work.

`.+` means at least one character, so `a.+a` would match an `a`, at least one but up to infinity other characters, followed by another `a`. `b.+b` works similarly, and then `|` works to OR the the two expressions together.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
(([ab]).*?\2)
```

##### Regex Explanation

- `(` Capturing group

  - `(` Capturing group

    - `[ab]` Match `a` or `b` character
  - `)` Close group
  - `.*?\2` Non-greedy match till the second group
- `)` Close group

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4zn0GI/1)

Answer (score 0):

As you do not want to capture `a` and `b` markers themself, you can use a positive lookbehind and lookahead.

As marker should be the same at the end as at the start you can use a capturing group in a lookaround.

So regex would be like this

```
(?<=([ab]))(.*)(?=\1)
```

Please, check a demo https://regex101.com/r/ebZRDz/3